# QML TabView creation order

Tags: qt, qml

Take the following code in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

TabView {
    Tab {
        id: firstTab
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("1")
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: firstTabRectangle
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("2")
            }
        }
    }
    Tab {
        id: secondTab
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("3")
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: secondTabRectangle
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("4")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the question is:

What does the console print when the code is executed?

I would have guessed

```
1 (firstTab)
2 (firstTabRectangle)
3 (secondTab)
```

But the result is:

```
3 (secondTab)
1 (firstTab)
2 (firstTabRectangle)
```

I understand that "4" gets not created because we see the `firstTab` "1" with the `firstTabRectangle` "2". So `secondTabRectangle` "2" is never created until we want to switch to the tab.

Comment: I don't think the order of declarative code is ever guaranteed.

Comment: I think it is. Can anyone get out another order than 3 1 2 when running this?

Comment: Why does order matter to your application?

Comment: Order does not matter for me. But it is a question I got asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news for you, my friend, according to documentation on [`completed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) signal:

> The order of running the handlers is undefined.

So better do not rely on its order.